# AirMail - Non breaking line tricks used as preview

Tags: html, css, email

I use this tricks on my email to handle (to prevent) responsive display (fonts enlarging) on mail client:

```
<div style="display:none; white-space:nowrap; font:15px courier; color:#ffffff;">
        - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
</div>
```

By now, my client just show me that his new AirMail app detect these chars and used them as preview.

I put this (the non-breakable div) at bottom of my emails, and at top, i defined hidden text to be used as preview by email client.

That worked until AirMail ...

[image]

Any suggestions, or others tricks to prevent responsive email?

EDIT:

Top of email

```
 <div style="display:none !important;height:1px;max-height:1px;opacity:0;visibility:hidden;font-size:0px !important;color:white;line-height:0px !important;mso-hide:all">
      <p style="display: none !important;">HIDDEN CONTENT TO BE USED AS PREVIEW</p>
 </div>
```

Middle of email

```
<table style="width:600px;max-width:600px;min-width:600px;padding:0px;margin:auto;" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
    <tbody>
        <tr>EMAIL CONTENT</tr>
    </tbody>
```

Bottom of email

```
    <div style="display:none; white-space:nowrap; font:15px courier; color:#ffffff;">
        - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    </div>
</table>
```

Comment: Just place this block under your preheader block.

Comment: I said that i "put this at bottom of my emails", so this is under my header text.

Comment: Didn't understood that from what you wrote. It would be easier if you add all the code of your newsletter.

Comment: I just do that:

https://css-tricks.com/override-gmail-mobile-optimized-email/

Comment: OK, but we still can't see your code in its globality. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a dashed border. That way the dashes wont be scanned as content, and instead a style. It will also work a lot better responsively. see the fiddle below.

https://jsfiddle.net/nma7psq1/

```
.email {
    width:100%;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    border-top: dashed 1px black;
    border-bottom: dashed 1px black;
}
```

Comment: I dont really understand your answer..
The purpose is to force 600px email width, not to decorate my div with dash ?!